# Why do I get an error of undefined function in chrome?

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, firefox

If url is a homepage *(i.e index.html)*, some css properties will be applied to some of its elements. The following script runs fine in `Mozilla Firefox` but gives an error in `Chrome` saying the function `contains` is undefined. Why is that ? Is it that, `Chrome` doesn't treat the variable `URL` as a string ?

```
var url = document.URL;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

if(url.contains("index.html")) {    
    document.links.item(0).style.color = "#FFFF00";
    document.links.item(0).style.borderBottom = "solid 2px white";

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

It is only supported in FF which is why you get the undefined error in chrome.

As the starting of the page states

> This is an experimental technology, part of the Harmony (ECMAScript 6)
>   proposal. Because this technology's specification has not stabilized,
>   check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note
>   that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject
>   to change in future version of browsers as the spec changes.

If you look at the compatibility table near the bottom, only FF is supported

As an alternative, you can always use

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

```
if( url.indexOf("index.html") > -1 ) {  }
```

Comment: A more well supported function that can give you similar functionality is `indexOf`.  Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yes I added it about the same time that you commented

Answer (score 3):

Edit, updated (see comments)

Try

```
var url = document.URL;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
// changed `/index.html/.test(url)` , which returned `true`,
// to `/index\.html/.test(url)`,
// escaping `.` in `/index.html/.test(url)` , 
// appear to "work"  at console , 
// though actually returned a `false` `true` 
// when testing for required string ,
// demonstrated by Derek 朕會功夫 , at comments
if(/index\.html/.test(url)) {    
    document.links.item(0).style.color = "#FFFF00";
    document.links.item(0).style.borderBottom = "solid 2px white";

}
```

Comment: Of course it "works" because `.` is the symbol for "1 character". Try `/index.html/.test("index9html")` and it returns an incorrect `true`.